# How do I extract what updates have been installed from CBS.log?

Tags: windows, windows-update, logging

I'm using AppDynamics to monitor our systems which has the ability to extract data from text logs so you can query them like a SQL table. What I want to do is extract when windows updates are installed, unfortunately most of the logs are etl files so I'm left with just the cbs.log.

Is CBS.log the right place to look for a text file that shows what updates were installed and when?

If so what should I be looking for in the log file to determine this?

Comment: Windows updates has its own list of updates that are installed and the date. I don't think they are written to the cbs log. Windows 10? There may be a windows command or powershell command that can query this over the network. Examples here, you just need to figure out how to do it over the network>>>>https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mu/2016/11/23/how-to-list-updates-that-have-been-installed-on-your-windows-server-2016-machine/

Comment: This command works on a local machine:  findstr /c:"Package_for_KB" %windir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log >"%userprofile%\Desktop\sfcdetails.txt"  it will output a text file with all kb updates to the desktop, not sure if this helps or not.

Comment: @Moab unfortunately I can't use a script, it needs to be a text file already on the file system to work with AppDynamics log analysis

Comment: There is no text file already on the system, it has to be created.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, CBS.log is not the right place to look. The problem is that cbs.log will tell you (in a very roundabout way) what Windows *packages* and *components* are being installed. But packages and components don't match up one-to-one with updates, and the same update may install different things on different machines. So it becomes an unmaintainable mess, which I've seen companies attempt several times and I hope not to see companies attempt again.

However, there may be a more direct solution to your problem. It appears that AppDynamics can read the Windows event logs with the help of an extension: https://www.appdynamics.com/community/exchange/windows-event-log-monitor/ .  If that extension works as described, then you should be in good shape, because Windows Update logs installs in the Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient/Operational log.